# Plotting logistic model with package visreg doesn´t work Data not found

Tags: r, plot, graph, visreg

My second question of the day: I want to use the `visreg` package to plot my logistic regression models. As long as I don't use the attribute "by" it works like a charm, but when I want to use it I get an error. The code I used to create my model is the following:

```
m3<- glm(alive ~ seatbelt*dvcat + sex + ageOFocc + airbag, family = binomial, data = nassCDS, start=)
summary(m3)
```

If I then use:

```
visreg(m3, "seatbelt", scale = "response")
```

I get the following result
[image]

which is just fine. But if I now add the "by" attribute I get an error:

```
visreg(m3, "seatbelt", by="dvcat", scale ="response")
```

[image]

I googled and as far as I understood it the function can't find the data to plot the model. But where can I supply the data? I already tried the "data=" attribute, but it wasn´t working for me (or I did it wrong). There is no console output that I can provide only the message on the graph itself. Can somebody help me? Kind regards, Jan :)

---

EDIT: I used the "nassCDS" datasat from vincent arel-bundocks github which you can find here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html I just inserted the column alive via the column dead so that i am able to use the logistic regression. Therefore i used the dplyr package with the following code:

```
nassCDS <- nassCDS %>% 
  mutate(dead1 = as.integer(dead)) %>%
  mutate(alive = sjmisc::rec(dead1, rec = "2=0; 1=1")) %>%
select(seatbelt, dead, alive, dvcat, sex, ageOFocc, everything()) %>% 
  select(-dead1)
```

Furthermore i changed the columns airbag and seatbelt to numeric as it was suggested by one other stackoverflow user.

Comment: Is `nassCDS` a default dataset coming with some package? If not then edit the question by copy and paste the output of `dput(nassCDS)`. Visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The dataset was a part of a former default package but not anymore. The output of the function dput() is way too long to copy it i think? I got the dataset from the github of a professor from canada: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html
You can just search for "nassCDS"

Comment: The dataset does not contain `alive` column rather it has `dead` and in your code `start=` is missing.

Comment: @BappaDas I edited my question above, providing the code i used to create the column alive.